# Problem with payment module

Tags: magento2, module, payment-methods, payment

I am creating a custom payment module for magento 2 and I am experiencing the following problem. I get an error on the method=renderer.js on the getCode function saying 'Cannot read property '[name of module]' of undefined'. After a little research I see that on cc-form.js I see the following

```
getCcAvailableTypes: function () {
            return window.checkoutConfig.payment.ccform.availableTypes[this.getCode()];
        },
```

The `window.checkoutConfig.payment.ccform` returns only the icon object.

This is my code on method_renderer.js

```
define(
[
    'Magento_Payment/js/view/payment/cc-form',
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Payment/js/model/credit-card-validation/validator'
],
function (Component) {
    'use strict';
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Vendor_Module/payment/module'
        },
        getCode: function() {
            return 'vendor_module';
        },
        isActive: function() {
            return true;
        },
        validate: function() {
            var $form = $('#' + this.getCode() + '-form');
            return $form.validation() && $form.validation('isValid');
        }
    });
}
```

);

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below code in your etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Payment\Model\CcGenericConfigProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="methodCodes" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="your item name" xsi:type="const">payment code name</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Comment: You are always welcome